# Box.com update/delete folder using curl

Tags: api, curl, request, put, box

I am trying to update the folder name in box.com using curl tool in windows command prompt. However, I am not able to do that and getting the "insufficient permissions" error. Following is the exact curl command I am using with the request parameters for updating the folder:

```
curl -i https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 -H "Authorization: Bearer rn4lh6kST6bhmaLEuZdjMtxXpTfORg1B" -d "{\"name\":\"New Folder Name!\"}'-X PUT
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
{"type":"error","status":403,"code":"access_denied_insufficient_permissions","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Access denied - insufficient permission","request_id":"11155318795551a7373138a"}
```

I get the same error for "DELETE" the folder command in curl.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with the quote escaping. Also, you have `-d "....'` (note the mismatched `"` and `'`

Try the following commands that are from **[Box API](https://box-content.readme.io/#folder-object-1)**: (Don't forget to add your folder ID & Access Token)

**Update Folders**

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '{"name":"New Folder Name!"}' -X PUT
```

**Delete Folders**

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID?recursive=true 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X DELETE
```

Comment: ' quote was a mistake I corrected in my syntax. The curl commands you have given can't be run on windows command prompt, as windows read the ' and  " in different manner. So I was using escape character. Anyways I really appreciate you for the response you have given, also would like to mention that my error has been resolved. I was giving folder id as "0". I had to give the specific folder id under parent ("0"). Could you tell me the way to delete multiple folders at one go in box?

Comment: You can use [https://www.cygwin.com/](Cygwin) to install cURL and other unix commands on Windows. Im not sure how to do it in 'one go'. Couldn't you just have the multiple commands be back to back?